# Simple ajax not successful

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I know this is probably a basic error that I have made so my apologies in advance but I did check and cannot find an answer that deals with a really basic ajax load issue like this.

I have attached all three files which I am using to test the basic functionality before making it more functional and adding it to a project I am working on.  Any help would be appreciated as I cannot see why my paragraph is not updating to the message in page.html?

ajax.js contains:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "page.html", 
            success: function(result){
                $("#content").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

page.html contains:

```
<p>Show this</p>
```

ajaxTest.html contains:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <body>
    <input type="button" value="Test Button" id="button" />

    <p id="content"></p>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./ajax.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rather than staring at the code, you could check the developer tools (F12) for errors.

Comment: The ajax url, must be a server page(like php), not an html page. That page should return something to ajax request. I think you should learn more about ajax request.

Comment: Did you have firebug install so errors will be shown in firebug console.

Comment: the page.html should be page.php and there you can use echo "show content"; that will help you

Answer (score 1):

Use browser debugging tool for debugging ajax request. If you are using chrome simply press `F12` and click on network tab.

[image]

And if you are using Firefox use can simply install `firebug`